# Seekbar or progress bar with multiple colors

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

[image]

I want to create a bar like this initially when progress is zero it will be a fade in color but and as progress goes on it will become bright on that part(This is best I can explain) main thing is i want bar to show all colors at the same time.

Comment: for that you should create 9 patch image.

Comment: In my opinion it's better to create a custom ProgressBar and set different images / colors depending on it's progress.

Comment: see if this could help http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-how-to-change-progress-bar.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Clip your "on" drawable:[image]
over your "off" drawable:[image]

by using `res/drawable/custom_progress_drawable.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Background -->
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar_off"/>

    <!-- Secondary progress - this is optional -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar_secondary" />
    </item>

    <!-- Progress -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar_on" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

From an `Activity`, use

```
Drawable progressDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.custom_progress_drawable, getTheme());
myProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
```

or in xml, use

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_drawable"
```

And here's the result when using `android:max="10"` in xml:

[image]

It's a little bit off, but you could use `setMax()` with something more like `10000` and do some offsetting calculations when calling `setProgress()` to make it cleaner.

Comment: Just to add some info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList
According to this you should put the max on 10.000
Note: The default level is 0, which is fully clipped so the image is not visible. When the level is 10,000, the image is not clipped and completely visible.

Comment: How to set this ProgressBar to be a vertical bar instead of horizontal?

Comment: I'm confused about what you do with `MyProgressBar.java`. Can you explain how to use this?

Answer (score 7):

Finally! I went on a mission to figure this out for you, so if this suffices, feel free to give me that bounty, haha.

---

Try using this in your layout:

```
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".20"/>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.62">
                <View android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".03"/>
                <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.94"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressmask"
                    android:progress="0"
                    android:max="10"
                    android:rotation="180"/>
                <View android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".03"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".18"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

which references this drawable (progressmask.xml):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="50dip" />
        <gradient android:startColor="#00000000" android:endColor="#00000000" android:angle="270" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="50dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#aa000000" android:endColor="#aa000000"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and this image (colorprogress.png)

[image]

What it does is set the image as the background of a linearlayout, which contains a progressbar. The progressbar adds a semi-transparent black mask to the image to make it appear that the lights are off.

NOTE: In order to get this affect, I had to monkey with the progress bar (i.e. flip it, and set it to only 10 intervals. You will have to do some math to get the progress to line up with the image. i.e. setprogress((100-trueprogress)/10). Sorry I did not do this part for you.

This is what it will look like at progress 50% (the small x's and triangles will disappear on the device)

[image]

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Ahh, darn. I have to admit, @UberPrinny 's answer was much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Like already suggested i think you should go for an layer-list and set multiple drawables then. 
Main problem on this is that i need to be resizeable. An fixed size solution would be quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually set the progress bars to different colors. You can however use only the `on` drawable and get the effect that you want. You could just apply a layer mask. What I mean is add a Relative layout which is initially say `dark grey` throughout i.e the gradient has only ONE color which is dark gray. Now, use [**code**](http://mobileapptrickz.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-class-extending.html) to set the gradient color on the left programmatically. Obviously the color on the left is going to be transparent. Learn more about [**Linear Gradients**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html). That's about it. You just need to calculate the position from where the  right gradient starts, rather where the left gradient(`transparent`)ends.

This method is slightly flawed and may not work on ALL devices.

The flawless method would be to create multiple `.9png` images and set the drawable of the progress dialog programmatically every time.