# Android customize progress bar

Tags: android

I want to know how I can create a progress bar that is like this:
[image: Sample Progress Bar]

I already have drawn the progress of the progress bar in image file, how am i going to put it into the progress bar?

my progress bar XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#ffffffff"
            android:endColor="#ffffffff"
            android:centerColor="#ffffffff"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress" >
        <shape>

        </shape>

</item>

</layer-list>
```

Thank you!

Comment: do you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this answer :- [MultiColorprogressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602814/multi-colour-progress-bar#answer-27603338)

Or try this plugin [SmoothProgressBar](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)