# Android horizontal progress bar with 4 colors

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to implement a progress bar which indicates 4 states. Say first state ranges from 0-25 where I need to show one color to indicate "low", second from 25-50 to show another color for "medium", third state from 50-75 with another color for "high" and the rest with another color for "critical". I have seen only examples with progress,secondaryProgress and background color implementation.Can some one tell me a solution for this?(Nb:I don't need the black separator in between)[image: progress_bar]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602814/multi-colour-progress-bar

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: please check this http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html

Comment: I have gone through the link already. But I didn't get an exact solution. I don't need gradient effect. Also while trying with this it is just drawn like a rectangle, not progressed. @sasikumar

Comment: Did u find any solution?