# Android Progress Circle With Multiple Colors

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I'm trying to draw a indeterminate (circular) progress bar that is white and then fades into purple.

This is my ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/mainProgressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Then I paint it white:

```
mainProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Do I need add another ColorFilter? Set a style or theme on the progressbar? No idea what to do here.

Comment: your code seems to be fine you have problems?

Comment: It's just one color.  I want my progressbar to have multiple colors

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602814/multi-colour-progress-bar or this lib https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Answer (score 2):

DonutProgressView is a configurable doughnut-like graph view capable of displaying multiple datasets with assignable colors. It supports animations and features a gap at the top, which makes it look like a gauge (or tasty bitten-off donut - that's why the name).

[Click Here to See Git Lib](https://github.com/futuredapp/donut?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=8015)