# custom view: horizontal stacked bar. Any libs?

Tags: android

Trying to implement so-called stacked Bar chart.

Horizontal bar with different colors depends of input data.

I'm going to write this custom view from scratch.
Does anyone know any libs that can do this? Seems it is common chart, but can't find lib..

[image: Like this]

Comment: why not building the view from scratch? It seems pretty easy to do. You can also upload it as library yourself

Comment: try this Link :
https://github.com/numetriclabz/numAndroidCharts

Comment: @matrix yep. Going to implement from scratch. Just wondered that there are no libs. Or I can't find..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602814/multi-colour-progress-bar