# How to add Multi Color ProgressBar in android

Tags: android, graph, comparison, android-progressbar

How i do i add android progress bar with multi color.
e.g Google shows a progress bar that there are 30% chance that a match will be drawn, 20%chance A team will win, 50% chance B team will win with three colors.

Comment: @HassebKhan  refer this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602814/multi-colour-progress-bar

Comment: @HassebKhan Can u post any image? that describe what you expect.