# Android buttery progress bar multiple color support

Tags: android, progress-bar

Recently i just discover a source to android kitkat's progress bar, very neat and fast implementation. I'm trying to make it support multiple colors like google+ but no success. Anybody here can help tweak this code to support multiple colors?

[Google buttery progress bar source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/kitkat-release/src/com/android/mail/ui/ButteryProgressBar.java)

Comment: check out this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413633/seekbar-or-progress-bar-with-multiple-colors

Answer (score 0):

So the code is written in java. This piece of code sets the color in a variable=
    mBarColor =     ta.getColor(R.styleable.ButteryProgress  Bar_barColor,                       c.getResources().getColor(android.R.col. or.holo_blue_light)); 
You have to set the color in the variable so lets say we want it to be green.The code will be:
    mBarColor = Color.green
Here are some  colorcodes: Color.black, Color.darkGray, Color.gray, Color.lightGray, Color.white, Color.magenta, Color.red, Color.pink, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.cyan, Color.blue .
Good luck