# How can you recreate this?

Tags: android

I need to recreate something exactly like this. A bar with a slider and with various colors, exactly the same. I was looking for a bit 'but I can not find a way to do it or anything like that. Can anyone give me a track to work on? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is

[Android seekbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)

And then to style it you would probably end up doing like this so answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27035469/2880747

or this one

[Custom seekbar (thumb size, color and background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background)

I personally used the latter, and it was working great :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Tomorrow I look good links that you left me! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problems. If it helped you, give it a +1 ;) and if it answered your answer accept it as your solution :)!

Comment: Adding to the Wilom answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413633/seekbar-or-progress-bar-with-multiple-colors and https://github.com/apptik/MultiSlider