# Custom Seekbar type of view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create a view like below :
[image]

Based on the range provided, the line background colour should change, also the circle colour. Is it correct way to create a customised seekbar to use for this scenario, anyone has done this kind of view?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413633/seekbar-or-progress-bar-with-multiple-colors

Comment: You can use
[this library](https://github.com/rtugeek/ColorSeekBar) ,
 I have used it before and it can give you your wanted look for your view

Answer (score 0):

For one of my app, I did something similar. Though I did not split the line. To change color programmatically use the below code.

```
seekBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
```